# Inserting a php variable in background-image

Tags: php

I'm trying to build a widget for a website that displays a random background image everytime the page is refreshed and i'm running into some trouble with string concatenation.

```
$display .= "<p class=\"ey-image-quote\" style\"background-image:url('".$img."')\">" . $this->quote . "</p>";
```

This returns a url without slashes (replaced by spaces) and i have not found a viable solution yet.
Is there any way to achieve this in php?

Comment: paste the output of `$img`

Comment: style needs a = after it

Comment: paste the final output of $display too

Comment: Surely you don't want the backslashes? All the blackslashes do is allow you to use `"` in your html. https://3v4l.org/rRm1Z . As @ProEvilz said, you're missing the `=` after `style` and then it should work

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```
$display .= "<p class=\"ey-image-quote\" style=\"background-image:url('".$img."')\">" . $this->quote . "</p>";
```

You forgot `=` in style